# What are the delegate methods for ReplayKit's initial alert choices?

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

When the the user first decides to use ReplayKit there is an alert that appears. It gives 3 choices:

```
-Record Screen and Microphone
-Record Screen Only
-Don’t Allow
```

What are the delegate methods so that I can find out which option a user choose?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any delegate methods to determine which option a user chooses. You have to use the [completionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder/2867291-startcapture) and [.isMicrophoneEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder/1620987-ismicrophoneenabled) to determine the chosen option.

Once an option is chosen the `completionHandler` is called:

1. If the user chooses `Don't Allow` then the `error` code will run
2. If the user chooses `Record Screen & Microphone` then `.isMicrophoneEnabled` will get set to `true`
3. If the user chooses `Record Screen Only` then `.isMicrophoneEnabled` will get set to `false`

Inside the `completionHandler` you can check to see their choice then do whatever you need to do from that point on. Read the 2 comments in the `completionHandler` part of the code below.

```
let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

recorder.startCapture(handler: { [weak self](buffer, bufferType, err) in

    // ...

}, completionHandler: { (error) in

    // 1. If the user chooses "Dont'Allow", the error message will print "The user declined application recording". Outside of that if an actual error occurs something else will print
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("The user choose Don't Allow")
        return
    }

    // 2. Check the other 2 options
    if self.recorder.isMicrophoneEnabled {

        print("The user choose Record Screen & Microphone")

    } else {

        print("The user choose Record Screen Only")
    }
})
```

The safe way to do this so that you know how to respond to [each error code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rprecordingerrorcode) is to use a switch statement on the error codes:

```
}, completionHandler: { (error) in

    if let error = error as NSError? {

        let rpRecordingErrorCode = RPRecordingErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
        self.errorCodeResponse(rpRecordingErrorCode)
    }
})

func errorCodeResponse(_ error: RPRecordingErrorCode?) {

    guard let error = error else { return }

    switch error {

    case .unknown:
        print("Error cause unknown")
    case .userDeclined:
        print("User declined recording request.")
    case .disabled:
        print("Recording disabled via parental controls.")
    case .failedToStart:
        print("Recording failed to start.")
    case .failed:
        print("Recording error occurred.")
    case .insufficientStorage:
        print("Not enough storage available on the device.")
    case .interrupted:
        print("Recording interrupted by another app.")
    case .contentResize:
        print("Recording interrupted by multitasking and content resizing.")
    case .broadcastInvalidSession:
        print("Attempted to start a broadcast without a prior session.")
    case .systemDormancy:
        print("Recording forced to end by the user pressing the power button.")
    case .entitlements:
        print("Recording failed due to missing entitlements.")
    case .activePhoneCall:
        print("Recording unable to record due to active phone call.")

    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Lance, If I get "Recording interrupted by multitasking and content resizing." error then how to handle it because without restarting iPhone this error will not go.

Comment: I never used multitasking before. You should ask that as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to detect when `Don't Allow` is tapped, here is a simple solution:

```
recorder.startCapture(handler: { [self] (sampleBuffer, sampleType, passedError) in
        if let passedError = passedError {
            print(passedError.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
            
        }) { err in
            if let error = err {
                if error._code == RPRecordingErrorCode.userDeclined.rawValue {
                    print("User didn't allow recording")
                }
            }
        }
```