# How to execute a function when the user allows Record Screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call a function in the moment the user taps into "Record Screen", how can I achieve that?

And the opposite? How can I execute another function when the user taps into "Don't Allow"?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the delegate methods for ReplayKit's initial alert choices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495052/what-are-the-delegate-methods-for-replaykits-initial-alert-choices)

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks!